# How to expand a branch without selecting it? (Tkinter Treeview)

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, selection

I want to select multiple children in a treeview, however each time I expand or collapse a node/branch by clicking on its handle, the node I clicked get selected or deselected such that I lose the selection. Is there a way to just collapse/expand the node period?

Here is a relevant extract of the code, even though I think it's a more general question:

```
class CommonControls: #Find a better name
    def __init__(self, window):
        #Common controls
        self.openBtn = Button(window,text='Select and open files')
        self.openBtn.pack(side='top', fill='x')
        
        self.pb = Progressbar(window, length=100)
        self.pb.pack(side='top', fill='x')
        
        self.tree = Treeview(window)
        self.tree.pack(expan=1,fill='both')

        #Add a tab widget and the individual tabs to the tab widget
        self.tabController = Notebook(window)

        #Insert the tab controller in the window, and make it span horizontally
        self.tabController.pack(side='bottom',fill ="x") #Expand=1 fill = both?
        
        self.swapTree = Button(window, text='Swap view', command=self.swapTreeview)
        self.swapTree.pack(side='bottom', fill='x')
        self.swappedView = False
        
        #Binds the callbacks to the buttons
        self.openBtn.bind("<Button-1>", self.open)
        
    #Private/protected methods
    
    def emptyTreeview(self):
        for i in self.tree.get_children():
            self.tree.delete(i)
        self.tree.update()
    
    def swapTreeview(self, event=None):
        treeMemParents = list()
        treeMemChildren = list() 
        
        #For each children of item 0
        
        for childIID in self.tree.get_children(self.tree.get_children()[0]):
            #Memorise child as a level 0 entry (new parent)
            treeMemChildren.append(self.tree.item(childIID, 'text')) #The IID for the children was parent:child. Get child only
            
        #For each item of level 0 (all parents), add them as new children
        for parentIID in self.tree.get_children():
            treeMemParents.append(parentIID)
                
        #For each item selected
            #Get iid and store it
        selIIDs = self.tree.selection()
            
        self.emptyTreeview()
        
        #Add tree view
        for childIID in treeMemChildren:
            self.tree.insert('', tk.END, iid=childIID, text=childIID)
            for parentIID in treeMemParents:
                self.tree.insert(childIID, tk.END, iid=parentIID+IID_SEP+childIID, text=parentIID)
        
        #for all items in the selection
            #Get item from iid
            #Select it
        self.tree.selection_set(selIIDs)
    
    def open(self, event=None):
        self.pb['value'] = 0
        
        self.emptyTreeview()
        
        filetypes = (('CSV files', '*.csv'),)
        filePaths = filedialog.askopenfilenames(title='Select test results files to process',
                                                initialdir='~',
                                                filetypes=filetypes)

        for iFile, filePath in enumerate(filePaths, 1):
            filename = basename(filePath)
            
            file = open(filePath)
            header = file.readline()
            if(iFile == 1):
                refTokens = header.split(CSV_DELIMITER)
            
            tokens = header.split(CSV_DELIMITER)
            
            ok = True
            for tok, refTok in zip(tokens, refTokens):
                if tok != refTok:
                    ok = False
                
            if(not ok):
                messagebox.showerror('Analysis error', 'All files selected must have exactly the same columns')
            else:
                self.tree.insert('', tk.END, iid=filename, text=filename)
                
                for iTok, tok in enumerate(tokens):
                    if iTok == 0:
                        continue #Skip time
                    
                    self.tree.insert(filename, tk.END, iid=filename+IID_SEP+tok, text=tok)
                    
            file.close()
            
            self.pb['value'] = iFile/len(filePaths)*100
```

Comment: Thanks, the title didn't match but some of the content did: now I can select individual children, but the "shift select" behaviour does not work - how can I forward the message to the tkinter treeview selection handler myself? Otherwise I'll have to write that feature as well but it feels like reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I've agreed to close the topic because this question is better suited to a separate thread.